# Visual C++ compiler's strange behavior

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I found something really interesting I think :).

```
#include <iostream>

const int y0 = 0;

int main() {
    return 0;
};
```

This program fails with error C2365 saying me that I try to redefine y0. It's defined in correct_math.h header file or whatever it is:

```
//near the end of correct_math.h

#ifndef __assembler
        #ifndef _M_CEE_PURE
            extern double HUGE;
        #else
            double const HUGE = _HUGE;
        #endif

        _CRT_NONSTDC_DEPRECATE(_j0) _Check_return_ _ACRTIMP double __cdecl j0(_In_ double _X);
        _CRT_NONSTDC_DEPRECATE(_j1) _Check_return_ _ACRTIMP double __cdecl j1(_In_ double _X);
        _CRT_NONSTDC_DEPRECATE(_jn) _Check_return_ _ACRTIMP double __cdecl jn(_In_ int _X, _In_ double _Y);
        _CRT_NONSTDC_DEPRECATE(_y0) _Check_return_ _ACRTIMP double __cdecl y0(_In_ double _X);
        _CRT_NONSTDC_DEPRECATE(_y1) _Check_return_ _ACRTIMP double __cdecl y1(_In_ double _X);
        _CRT_NONSTDC_DEPRECATE(_yn) _Check_return_ _ACRTIMP double __cdecl yn(_In_ int _X, _In_ double _Y);
    #endif // !__assembler
```

So, is it error of compiler or it's me not understanding something?

Comment: what compiler are you using and what is the message of C2365 ?

Comment: Looks like the problem is your compiler for some reason already has a `y0` variable defined.

Comment: cool, here is it on godbolt with recent msvc: https://godbolt.org/z/nbvdbqeG5   :D

Comment: @drescherjm thought the same, but no `using namespace std;` needed

Comment: note that visual studio is an IDE, what matters is the compiler. The most probable is msvc but the same IDE can use different compilers. You should include the information on used compiler in the question. Also error codes are not universal, not everybody is used to msvcs error codes, but everybody can read a compilers error message.

Comment: I get the same error using clang-cl (in Visual Studio 2022).

Comment: It's probably a good idea to have the own code always embedded in an own namespace (except `main()`, of course). I do this for a long time although I wasn't aware of the things I might have run into otherwise.